# How to make a percentage appear in the other input bar?

Tags: javascript, input, numbers, percentage

I'm trying to add JaveScript to my html input bars, what I want is for when someone enters a certain amount of money in one an equivalent amount of percentage will automatically appear in the other. For instants: typing 6000 in one box will cause the other to show 6%.

const btnOne = document.querySelector('.btn1');

const btnTwo = document.querySelector('.btn2');

```
object.addEventListener("click", myScript); 

function myScript(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(btnOne.nodeValue === '6000') {
    btnTwo.innerHTML = '<h1>6%</h1>';
    }
}



  <!--goal window-->  <!--html-->
    <div class="goal-window">
<div class="goal-window-container">
    <div class="goal-status-and-text">
    <h2 class="goal-text">goal <br> 6,000 = 6%</h2></div>
    <h4><a><br>pledged of 14,000.00 = 14%</a></h4>
    <div class="pledge"><h2>pledge the amount relitive
     to the percentage<br>you would like to purchase.</h2></div>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="pay-section"> 
      <input class="btn1" type="text" placeholder="$" name="lname">
      <h2 class="equal-sign">=</h2> 
      <input class="btn2" type="text" placeholder="%" name="lname"><br>
      </div>    
 <button class="invest-button">invest</button>
</form>
</div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>



/* ### goal window ### */ /*###CSS###*/

.goal-window {
    width: 96%;
    height: 40rem;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888;
    border: 4px solid rgb(187, 183, 183);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.goal-window-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.goal-text {
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.goal-status-and-text {
   display: flex;
   height: 4rem;
   align-items: center;
   margin-top: 2rem;
}

.goal-number {
    height: 4rem;
    border: 4px solid rgb(187, 183, 183);
}

.pledge {
    text-align: center;
}

input {
    border: 4px solid black;
    height: 2rem;
}

.equal-sign {
    padding: 0 8px;
}

.pay-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
/* ### invest botton ### */

.invest-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 6rem;
    margin-top: 4rem;
}

hr {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-top: 6rem;
}
```

Comment: So.... what is the problem?

Comment: You need to give more details. What is the existing code? How does 6000 = 6%? You aren't giving any details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're literally just hardcoding a specific value into the view. What you need to do is get what the user typed in, convert it to its percent value, and update the view with the new percent. Here is an example

```js
document.getElementById('num-input').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
 let val = e.target.value;
 let percent = parseFloat(val / 1000);
 document.getElementById('percent').value = percent;
})
```

```html
<input id="num-input" type="number" placeholder="enter a number">
<input id="percent" disabled>
<span>%</span>
```